# Office-js addin with webapi on Azure. Fetch error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, office-js

Windows 10  20H2, VS 2019 Community

Application contains one office-js addin (typescript) + one Webapi core (c#) in a container, both components communicating with a fetch function thanks to cors.
It works properly on my local computer.
I published both components on azure, the webapi component being derived as a container instance. I checked that the correct azure addin address was entered in the webapi startup module.

Now, each  individual component works  properly (proof with messages from the addin and with postman for the webapi)  but fetch function raises errors (message = "failed to fetch).

Could someone tell me what I did miss ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please lemme know the function you are fetching is on azure or still on local?

Comment: This function is a "post" to a controler in the webapi + some JSON parameter. When I test it on my computer it works locally and gives the expected results; but as soon one of its member is on azure (as an office addin or as an instance container of then webapi) it is doesn't work and fidder shows no traffic wheras postman shows the webapi is correctly working

Answer (score 0):

Closed. Finally it was about :

- debugging in localhost is not enough. You have to test with Swagger. In my case I had a wrong return with a String[] and the decoration of the controller was not ok
- having a plain Web api application (ie : with a wwwroot)